# Unique identifier (place_id) to coordinates

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am currently donwloading Tweets using the twitter API. I am looking for tweets with a location (cities, pois). This works so far.
In the response I get the name of the place, the type of the place and a unique place id (see below).

`{'full_name': 'Mannheim, Deutschland', 'place_type': 'city', 'id': '4555d5a205d63969', 'name': 'Mannheim', 'geo': {'type': 'Feature', 'bbox': [8.414251, 49.410381, 8.590021, 49.590376], 'properties': {}}}`

I would like to create a coordinate for each city/poi using the id, since I would like to plot the tweets. Is this possible?

Kind regards,
Daniel

Comment: The values in `bbox` look a lot like coordinates to me.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Maybe it's an estimated location since Twitter doesn't scrap the exact location of the tweets?

Comment: It's a bounding box for the city, which is what the user has added as a place to their Tweet. You will not get exact coordinates and only a tiny percentage of Tweets carry geo information.